# How to read a file line by line and return how many bytes have been read?

Tags: go

The case is :

1. I want read the log like "tail -f" *NIX
2. when I kill the program I can know how many bytes I have already read,and I can use the seek
3. when the program start again,will continue to read the log line by line depend by seek data in step 2

I want get the bytes when I use bufio.NewScanner as a line reader to read a line

eg:

```
import ...
func main() {
    f, err := os.Open("111.txt") 
    if err != nil {          
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    f.Seek(0,os.SEEK_SET)
    scan := bufio.NewScanner(f)
    for scan.Scan() {
        log.Printf(scan.Text())
        //what I want is how many bytes at this time when I read a line
    }//This is a program for read line
```

}

thx!
==================================update==========================================
@twotwotwo this is close to what I want,but I want change the **io.Reader** to the **io.ReaderAt**, and it is what I want,I write a demo use the **io.Reader**:`

```
import (
   "os"
   "log"
   "io"
)
type Reader struct {
    reader io.Reader
    count  int
}
func (r *Reader) Read(b []byte) (int, error) {
    n, err := r.reader.Read(b)
    r.count += n
    return n, err
}
func (r *Reader) Count() int {
    return r.count
}
func NewReader(r io.Reader) *Reader {
    return &Reader{reader: r}
}

func ReadLine(r *Reader) (ln int,line []byte,err error) {
    line = make([]byte,0,4096)
    for {
        b := make([]byte,1)
        n,er := r.Read(b)
        if er == io.EOF {
            err = er
            break
        }
        if n > 0{
            c := b[0]
            if c == '\n' {
                break
            }
            line = append(line, c)
        }
        if er != nil{
            err = er
        }
    }

    ln = r.Count()
    return ln,line,err
}

func main() {
    f, err := os.Open("111.txt")
    if err != nil {          
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fi,_:=os.Stat("111.txt")
    log.Printf("the file have %v bytes",fi.Size())
    co := NewReader(f)
    for {
        count,line,er := ReadLine(co)
        if er == io.EOF {
            break
        }
        log.Printf("now read the line :%v",string(line))
        log.Printf("in all we have read %v bytes",count)


    }

}`
```

this Program can tell me how many bytes I have already read,but cannt read start from anywhere where I want,so I think that if we use **io.ReaderAt** must can do it.
thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You could consider another approach based on [`os.File`](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#File).

See **[ActiveState/tail](https://github.com/ActiveState/tail)**, which monitor the state of a file, and uses [os.File#Seek()](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Seek) to resume tailing a file from within a certain point.

See [`tail.go`](https://github.com/ActiveState/tail/blob/master/tail.go#L35-L39).

Comment: thx,I have been saw it before I asked at there,but it can't solve my problem.

Answer (score -1):

Consider composition.

We know that `bufio.NewScanner` is interacting with its input through the `io.Reader` interface.  So we may wrap an `io.Reader` with something else that counts how many bytes have been read so far.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "bytes"
    "io"
    "log"
)

type ReadCounter struct {
    io.Reader
    BytesRead int
}

func (r *ReadCounter) Read(p []byte) (int, error) {
    n, err := r.Reader.Read(p)
    r.BytesRead += n
    return n, err
}

func main() {
    b := &ReadCounter{Reader: bytes.NewBufferString("hello\nworld\testing\n")}
    scan := bufio.NewScanner(b)
    for scan.Scan() {
        log.Println(scan.Text())
        log.Println("Read", b.BytesRead, "bytes so far")
    }
}
```

But we'll note that `bufio.NewScanner` is buffered, so we can see that it reads its input in chunks.  So for your purposes, this might not be as useful as you want.

An alternative is to take the content of `scan.Text()` and count up the lengths.  You can compensate for its removal of newline bytes in your internal count.

Comment: Facebook (specifically the Parse team) wrote [a `counting.Reader` and `counting.Writer`](https://gowalker.org/github.com/facebookgo/counting). It sounds like asker would really like to know start position + bytes written (which wouldn't include any partial line read at exit).

Comment: @dyoo thanks for ur answers, it's looks like the facebook's project told by twotwotwo . and I have been updated the question.